# django inline formset to upload multiple files not rendering form

Tags: python, django, formset, inline-formset

I have model:

```
class MediaInfo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    media_file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Media(models.Model):
    media_files = models.ForeignKey(MediaInfo)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.media_files
```

What I want is to render a template where I get a simple browse button and I can select and upload multiple 'media_file'.

I came to know that it can be performed from inline formset so used it in my view. My view looks like

```
def MediaAddView(request):
    #med = MediaInfo.objects.al()
    MediaInlineFormset = inlineformset_factory(MediaInfo, Media)
    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = MediaInlineFormset(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("some url")
        else:
            return render_to_response("media_add.html",
                {"formset":formset,},
                context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        formset = MediaInlineFormset()
        return render_to_response("media_add.html", 
            {"formset":formset,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and my template is :

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {{form.media_file}}
    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

When I do this instead of getting a browse button to upload file I am getting only submit button.

How can I get just a browse button and add multiple files or images ?

Whats wrong in my code ?
Need help

Comment: Where is `get_upload_file_name` ?

Comment: Thats a function I wrote to store file...

Comment: Just asking because I didn't see it in your code.

Comment: Are you getting errors? or just no output?

Comment: No errors... just no output...

Comment: That's usually indicative of an exception happening that's being suppressed by the template. Try looping over your forms in the view and see if you can print each one to the console.

Comment: Ohk I ll do that... but I found another better solution for multiple file update.. :)

Comment: @gamer, what solution did you end up using?

Comment: Also, instead of ``{{form.media_file}}``, try ``{{ form.as_p }}``

Comment: creating multiple file upload field in form :)